# NodeJS /Electron Confusion about client/server code

Tags: node.js, electron

This is a beginner kind of question. I haven't used NodeJS before, so it's a bit confusing to me. I don't see a clear separation between server modules and client modules. It seems like I can use "npm" (Node's package manager) to install both client modules and server modules.

My question is specifically related to this page:
http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.8/api/synopsis/

It says that I can use Node modules on client side:

> The renderer process is no different than a normal web page, except for the extra ability to use node modules:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <script>
      const remote = require('electron').remote;
      console.log(remote.app.getVersion());
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

How does this make any sense? Node is running on the server side, how is the browser ("renderer" process as they call it) able to use Node's packages?

Answer (score 7):

main process & renderer != server & client

NodeJS is Server side, not client side.
On a desktop app, you don't have to have a server.
But with electron you can use node direct in you app.

**The easy way:** With electron, think of NodeJS as a Toolbox to do cool stuff.
Like Filesystem manipulation and forget the client and server thing.

(Things you cant do with jquery etc. but things you need for a Desktop-App)

#### Electron: Main Process and Renderer

The **main process** is for handling/creating BrowserWindows(Renderer)
And for some communication from one renderer-Window to an other one.
(maybe some other special stuff too)

The **renderer** is where you really run the most of your app.
With node, you have all you need there.
Easy debugging (chrome dev tools) all in one place.

#### Node example in renderer

You can require ["fs" > NodeJS File System](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream)
To read Files or Folders from your Harddrive.

You can do this for a example in the html File (script tag)
which is display by the Renderer/Browser window.

---

It was very confusing for me too and my answer is for sure not perfekt and fully right.
But my tip is, try do everything in the renderer. When you have to use the main process you will notice that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for their answers. I think I understand now after reading this page:

http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.8/api/remote/

So, I completely misunderstood what Electron is. I thought it's basically a HTTP server running on NodeJS and a Chromium browser, so I thought the separation between client and server should be the same as it is when creating a website.

However, that's not how it is at all. It seems that you can actually communicate directly with the server via IPC (inter-process communication), so it's not the same as a HTTP client/server at all:

> The remote module provides a simple way to do inter-process communication (IPC) between the renderer process (web page) and the main process.

Answer (score 0):

I think what they are trying to say is you can use modules usually designated for Node to be used on the front end as well.  Since Electron was designed to be used as a desktop application instead of a browser they let you swap code around more easily.

I am not entirely sure when you'd want to use this most of the time.  I would assume they did this for easier integration of things like bluebird.js which is a promise library that I could see easily being used on both front-end and back-end packages even if it is mostly just used for NodeJS.

What that code is showing you is you can import a module via:

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;
console.log(remote.app.getVersion());
```

What this is saying load up my 'server-side' app with `('electron').remote` and now let me call those packages via `remote.app.bluebird` for example.  You may not every need or want to use this, but it's available.

I think the awesome thing about this is if you build a library specifically for Electron, you can write it in a way to make it more seamless across server-side and client-side.  This would be kind of how socket.io works if you've ever used it.  Server-side and client-side are nearly identical syntax, but they had to write them seperately so one worked server-side and one worked client-side.  With this, it might be possible to use the same code base for everything.

Although again, I don't know exactly what a good/perfect use case might be.  Granted I think you could keep a JSON store on one side, and just pull it in with imports which is kind of neat, again not sure how useful it is though.

Answer (score 0):

In the [official electron tutorial](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture#using-nodejs-apis) they states:

> You can use Node.js modules in your application. Pick your favorite
>   npm module. npm offers currently the world's biggest repository of
>   open-source code – **the ability to use well-maintained and tested code
>   that used to be reserved for server applications is one of the key
>   features of Electron.**
>
> As an example, to use the official AWS SDK in your application, you'd
>   first install it as a dependency:
>
> ```
> npm install --save aws-sdk
> ```
>
> Then, in your Electron app, require and use the module as if you were
>   building a Node.js application:
>
> ```
> // A ready-to-use S3 Client
> const S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3')
> ```

In this way Electron is way different to normal Web Apps where you can't just use some node module from npm to get the job done.

As pointed out in the official electron tutorial **"this is one of the key features of Electron."** because it makes solving certain problems way easier.

Imagine for example, that you want to write a simple markdown app. There is a node module called [`markdown-it`](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it). Using Electron you can just *require* and use it directly from within your client-side/render-process code, as done in the [implementation for *StudyMD*](https://github.com/jotron/StudyMD/blob/e444a810e8be8ba5e5ed328c94d358c7015e017c/src/components/home/logic.js#L10).